# Marking the entire line using Visual Studio Editor Extension Points

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mef, vspackage

I would like to mark an entire line on the editor according to some logic in my VSPackage.
So I exported `IClassifierProvider` and `EditorFormatDefinition` and succeeded marking the relevant line by setting `BackgroundColor` on `ClassificationFormatDefinition`.

However, the problem is that the line is not "entirely" marked, only the text and whitespace are marked.
When there are tabs on the beginning of the line, the mark is "intermittent" between them. Also, the mark does not span after end-of-line.

I would prefer the marker to start at the left edge of the editor window and extend until the right edge of the editor window, no matter how long the text line is.

Perhaps Classification Formats are not the best solution here. But what is the alternative?
(preferred a simple one. I guess I could get the window handle and draw the marker myself...)

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the "Editor Text Adornment" project template. That project highlights all of the "a"s in a document. I'd imagine you could pretty easily get the top and bottom of the row from the result of the `GetMarkerGeometry` call that's in the example. Then you could make an element that spans the whole width of the text view (`_view.ViewportWidth`).

*Edit*: Note that this is in Visual Studio 2012. I'm not sure that project template exists in the 2010 SDK.